# Groovy simplify new ChangeListener

Tags: groovy, javafx

I am writing a software using JavaFX in Groovy

I have a TabPane and I want to listen for changes in selected tab

The following block of code is not very pretty, is it possible to simplify it using idiomatic Groovy code?

```
    documentTabs.selectionModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
        @Override
        void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldValue, Tab newValue) {
            println newValue
        }
    })
```

I thought I could do something like this but it does not work

```
    documentTabs.selectionModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener({
        println it
    } as ChangeListener)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does not work in what way?

Comment: It throws an exception `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.oxysoft.dialogs.controllers.MainDialogController$_initialize_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl, null, javafx.scene.control.Tab) values: [ReadOnlyObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel@16210aba, name: selectedItem, value: javafx.scene.control.Tab@11f9ab07], ...]
Possible solutions: doCall(), call(), doCall(java.lang.Object), findAll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the event handler arguments to your closure, like this:

```
 documentTabs.selectionModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener({observable, oldValue, newValue ->
    println it
    } as ChangeListener)
```